# Increase speed on start and slow down at end

Tags: javascript, math

I have simple function that moves a circle in specific direction:

```
var rad = (a) => Math.PI / 180 * a;

this.x += Math.cos(rad) * this.throttle();
this.y += Math.sin(rad) * this.throttle();
```

I am also calculating distance to a target:

```
var distance = (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y) );

this.destination_distance = parseInt(distance( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: x, y: y } ));
```

I started to work on `this.throttle` function but i cannot get my head around it.

I wanted to achieve simple thing, when circle starts to move i want to increase speed from `min` to `max` by some step and when it is close to destination i want it to start slow down until it reaches `min`.

This is my current approach:

```
this.min_speed = 0.1;
this.max_speed = 1.5;
this.current_speed = 0.1;

this.throttle = function() {
    if(this.destination_distance > 300) {
        this.current_speed += 0.002;
    } else {
        this.current_speed -= 0.002;
    }

    if(this.current_speed < this.min_speed) {
        this.current_speed = this.min_speed;
    }

    if(this.current_speed > this.max_speed) {
        this.current_speed = this.max_speed;
    }

    return this.current_speed;
};
```

This doesnt work, because if the distance is smaller then `300` it doesnt speed up at all its always on `min` speed, so i suppose it should be somehow related to the `distance` variable. Maybe someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: What you need is a `Math.log`.

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
        console.log(Math.log(i))
    }

Comment: could you build it into function throttle so i can try it and better understand, thank You in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the difference between target speed and current speed, then add some specific fraction of that.

```
this.throttle = function() {
  var target_speed = this.destination_distance > 300 ? this.max_speed : this.min_speed;
  var diff = target_speed - this.current_speed;
  this.current_speed += diff * laziness;
  return this.current_speed;
};
```

`laziness` is something between `0.0001` and `1`; the greater the value the faster the change of velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Your starting speed is your minimum speed, so if the starting distance is <300 the circle will never speed up or slow down. Why not make your starting speed depend on the initial distance? Here's a crude implementation

```
if (this.destination_distance<300) {
    this.current_speed = 1.5; //start fast when in the deceleration zone
} else {
    this.current_speed = 0.1; //start slow when in the acceleration zone
}
```

Comment: the problem is i want always a throttle up and throttle down regardless of distance, it looks odd if the ship is standing still and suddenly at full speed

Comment: Then instead of using 300 in your code, you just need to use half of the initial destination_distance. Then it will accelerate for half the distance, then decelerate for half the distance, regardless of the starting positions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like percent of total distance passed? That way you will avoid having hardcoded threshold of 300 and it should work with distances of arbitrary length (with some tweaking of the speeds). Your changed function would look something like this:

```
this.throttle = function() {
    if(this.destination_distance > 0.5 * total_distance) {
        this.current_speed += 0.002;
    } else {
        this.current_speed -= 0.002;
    }

    if(this.current_speed < this.min_speed) {
        this.current_speed = this.min_speed;
    }

    if(this.current_speed > this.max_speed) {
        this.current_speed = this.max_speed;
    }

    return this.current_speed;
};
```

Here I consider total_distance to be the distance from the start to the final destination. This way the circle will travel approximately half of the way with increasing speed and the other half with decreasing speed. If you replace 0.5 by let 0.8 then the speed will increase for the first 80% and decrease for the last 20% of the path.

Comment: this one is very good approach, i already went that direction, but now i am having problem that it is slowing to fast or too slow, i am thinking to use the value of slow down and speed up as some number related to distance too.

Comment: you should try to make it a function of the distance, so for smaller distances the speed change would be slower. If your code from the question was tested with distance=<distance> and the speed change was 0.002, then if we try with the same proportion, we have: <distance> / 0.002 = new_distance / new_speed, so new_speed = new_dist * 0.002 / <distance>. This is off the top of my head, so I am not sure if that would give great results, but it's worth trying.

Comment: yeah i will try this method and see what happens

Comment: In the previous comment speed is actually the speed change (0.002 in your code) and distance is the total distance. You should also try the same thing with the current_speed.